# Mobile Stylesheet

Tags: css, internet-explorer, mobile

What would be the best way to get the nav system looking like the [main](http://www.dermaroller.com.au.com.au) site when using an mobile device?

The client has requested that the site works in IE7 and it now displays fine but instead it has altered the mobile view:

I am guessing it has something to do with the `display:block;` in the below style:

**Style:**

```
#navigation {

    float: left;
    display: block!important;
    margin-top: -3px;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use * before the statement, it will be only read by IE7 and below.

```
navigation {
  ...
  *display: block !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks,  Now I have lost the nav menu on the bar